# CSS3 animation rotateSpinner didn't work

Tags: css

```
img {
text-align: center;
width: 20px;
margin: auto;
display: block;
-webkit-animation: rotateSpinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/cfe2ym54/

What is the problem here?

Comment: You haven't declared a `rotateSpinner` animation anywhere. And, you are only using the WebKit vendor prefix, which is being phased out and will not work in non-WebKit browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add `keyframes`

```css
img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: rotateSpinner 1.2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotateSpinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateSpinner {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateSpinner {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <img src="http://assets.57square.com/img/loading.png">
</div>
```